# Cookies or Session on Google Apps Script Webservice

Tags: session, cookies, google-apps-script

I've created websites before where the server-side code has access to either Cookies on the browser or some sort of Session variables. I have not figured out how to do this with GAS. I can host a website with GAS, but I have no way of seeing the login session when a new page is loaded. How do I do this?

I would expect to see this information in the doGet() event, like this:

```
function doGet(e){
  e.session.userid; //or something like this
}
```

NOTE: Anyone can access my site, even anonymous. So I can't rely on Google logins.

Comment: Is the webapp published to run as the developer or the user?

Comment: Have a look at Session.getTemporaryActiveUserKey() https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getTemporaryActiveUserKey()

Comment: @SpencerEaston: It runs as the developer. The end user may or may not have a Gmail account, it is not required.

Comment: @AntonDementiev: I tried `Session.getTemporaryActiveUserKey()`. However, that only works if the user is logged into Gmail. If the user is not logged into Gmail, it generates a a key for "Anonymous", which is the same key for ALL anonymous users (even on different PC's). I need something that is unique to the browser session. That's *almost* what I need though!

Answer (score 1):

Google has a Session method.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session

```
 // Log the email address of the person running the script (visiting the page).
 var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
 Logger.log(email);
```

Edit:

In regard to the comment about cookie based identification.

I am no expert at this but my thought was to do something like this

Client JS

```
$(function(){
    var clientCookie = document.cookie
    google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(cookieString){
        if(cookieString){
            document.cookie= cookieString
        }
    })
    .craeteCookie(clientCookie) // server function to create cryptographic cookie string  
})
```

Server Side

```
function createCookie(clientCookie){
    if(clientCookie){
        //check cookie is valid
    }
    else{
        // create client cookie
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this does not work. This only works for Gmail users. This does not work if the user does not have a Gmail account. I need to support this, as I stated in my original post.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize that. I stumbled on this post looking for a similar solution for anonymous users.

I was also unable to find anything useful. I am thinking that I will implement my own ID based cookie identification.

Comment: How will you do that? All I've been able to find is ways to identify the user on the client side... I need to do it on the server side! Do you have a work around for this?