# Global Variable Bug in Google Apps Script Server Side

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to create global variables in Apps Script and avoid built-in functions such as UserProperties. The reason for avoiding UserProperties is because all of my web app users will share the same variables which will result in their accounts being mixed together. I want to create global variables that have a lifetime until you close the tab/window. I can't use user properties because I need to run the script as myself as I am searching within a spreadsheet under my account in this web app.

```
function extractData(row){
  extractEmail(row);
  extractPoints(row);
  extractUsername(row);
  extractName(row);
  extractType(row);
  extractFamily(row);
  return "success";
}

function extractEmail(row){
  try{
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pIC6Lyx4Q0ZjEA5GURZ3gA5qLmUJ0_7yGPJQmr6-GnQ/edit?usp=sharing";
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var subsheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Accounts");
    var col = 2
    Gemail = String(subsheet.getRange(Number(row), col).getValue());
  }
  catch(error){
    Logger.log(error.message);
    }
}

function extractPoints(row){
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pIC6Lyx4Q0ZjEA5GURZ3gA5qLmUJ0_7yGPJQmr6-GnQ/edit?usp=sharing";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var subsheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Accounts");
  var col = 6;
  Gpoints = Number(subsheet.getRange(Number(row), col).getValue());
}

function extractUsername(row){
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pIC6Lyx4Q0ZjEA5GURZ3gA5qLmUJ0_7yGPJQmr6-GnQ/edit?usp=sharing";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var subsheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Accounts");
  var col = 4;
  Gusername = String(subsheet.getRange(row, col).getValue());
}

function extractName(row){
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pIC6Lyx4Q0ZjEA5GURZ3gA5qLmUJ0_7yGPJQmr6-GnQ/edit?usp=sharing";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var subsheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Accounts");
  var col = 3;
  Gname = String(subsheet.getRange(row, col).getValue());
}

function extractType(row){
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pIC6Lyx4Q0ZjEA5GURZ3gA5qLmUJ0_7yGPJQmr6-GnQ/edit?usp=sharing";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var subsheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Accounts");
  var col = 7;
  Gtype = String(subsheet.getRange(row, col).getValue());
}

function extractFamily(row){
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pIC6Lyx4Q0ZjEA5GURZ3gA5qLmUJ0_7yGPJQmr6-GnQ/edit?usp=sharing";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var subsheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Accounts");
  var col = 12;
  Gfamily = String(subsheet.getRange(row, col).getValue());
  Logger.log(Gfamily);
}

function definer(){
  try{
  Utilities.sleep(5000);
  Logger.log(Gfamily);
  var data = [Gemail, Gname, Gusername, Gpoints, Gtype, Gfamily];
  return data;
  }
  catch(error){
    Logger.log(error.message);
  }
}
```

The code above is the server-side. Each function is called by the client-side along with the row already defined. The first function called by the client-side is **extractData**. When the global variable **Gfamily** is logged, it comes out correctly as **testers**. After the next function: **definer** is called from the client-side, **Gfamily** is logged as **null**. Please tell me how I can improve this question if I was unclear about anything. Below is a screenshot of the logs:
[Screenshot: Stackdriver logs showing how Gfamily suddenly becomes undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQeOb.png)

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for session variables, not global variables. I don't know Google App Scripts, so I don't know if it has this.

Comment: Looks like it does, the `Session` class. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573749/cookies-or-session-on-google-apps-script-webservice

Comment: I think that in your script, when `launch()` is run under with and without enabling V8 at the script editor, `Logger.log(globalVariable)` in `second()` shows `test`. So can I ask you about the detail flow for replicating your issue of `globalVariable gets logged as null`? By the way, if you want to make users use the same variables, how about using `getScriptProperties()` instead of `getUserProperties()`? But I'm not sure about your actual situation. So if this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: You might be able to use UserProperties rather than ScriptProperties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your frontend (browser) session is separate from your backend (server) session. Google's server isn't really tracking whether a user closes the tab/window, so you're going to have to manage the session from the frontend and then write your own server functions to correctly identify sessions.

To share a value across multiple users, I recommend using the [Script Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) or [Script Cache](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache). Values stored in the script properties/cache will be available to *all* users of your web app. If one user updates the value, the new value will be immediately available to all other users. I recommend using this with [Window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), which will clear automatically when the page session ends. So you could pass session data to the server and then manually track when a session is ended.

However, I don't really understand how you intend to use a shared value dependent on multiple user sessions. If one of the users ends their session, what happens to the shared value?

That makes me think there may be some misinterpretation, particularly due to your sentence

> The reason for avoiding UserProperties is because all of my web app users will share the same variables which will result in their accounts being mixed together.

User properties are not shared, *unless* you deployed the app to "[Execute the app as me](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#permissions)". If you did that, then the script would always be executing under the same (your) user account and all user properties *would* be shared. But if you were to simply set "Execute the app as user accessing the web app", then you could safely use User properties/cache without any worries about mixed accounts. (The intention of User properties/cache is to avoid scope issues like mixing across accounts – take a look at this [comparison table](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties#comparison_of_property_stores).)

Comment: Thank you Diego for your answer. I am very sorry for how unclear I was the first time I asked the question. I just updated my question and hopefully it's more clear now. I included a snippet of my actual code this time.

Comment: @DavidFahim Return the value of `Gfamily` to the frontend and use window.sessionStorage (mentioned above) to save it. Then pass that value into `definer()` whenever you call it.